# Sharia marriage/Nikah: what happens to the groom's assets if he dies?

Tags: nikah, inheritance

Salam alaykum!

My family and I are wondering about the islamic rulings on the groom's assets should he die. This question mainly bothers my areligious parents, who fear I would die young and briefly after an islamic marriage and that my wife would inherit all my possessions. They fear this because all our family's assets belong, on paper, to my sister and I.

To them, this means that a girl they barely know and will never see again would be able to run away with half their assets, when they would prefer these shift to my sister.

What are the rulings in nikah regarding this hypothetical situation? Will my future spouse, in fact, be able to claim all my possessions should I die one day after marriage?

I thank you for reading my question and any efforts to answer!

Comment: Nikah mutah is a special type of marriage contract that is valid in Shia Islam, there is no inheritance in it AFAIK. In a normal nikah the wife gets 1/4th if you have no children and 1/8 if you have children ([4:12](https://legacy.quran.com/4/12)).

Comment: However I don't understand your question, in practice your local law will be enforced and your wife may as well be entitled to all your assets, irrespective of what the Islamic law is?

Comment: Yes, my local law would not allow her to inherit anything as any muslim marriage wouldn't change my legal marital status. However, I plan to change my inheritance plan to follow islamic ruling (through a testament). 
My question is regarding the change in inheritance that applies after the sharia marriage. Apparently I have mistakenly called it Nikah mutah? I'm a convert, so I am not familiar enough; but my fiancee's family are sunni and have spoken to me about a different kind of marriage which would allow us to travel together (without any sexual activity)

Comment: Any nikah would allow you to travel together, and would also allow sexual activity, I do not know what kind of marriage they are referring to. The distribution of your estate would depend on which heirs exist. There are some islamic inheritance calculators available online which you can experiment with. The share of a wife is already given in my comment above, however keep in mind that it may increase if you do not have any other Muslim heirs. Non-muslims relations do not inherit from a Muslim however you may make a bequest of upto 1/3rd for them.

Comment: Thank you, that answers everything I needed to know. My parents will not like it though, as they are not muslim but would want all my possessions back should I die...